# How to mention "waiting for results" on CV?

Tags: resume, results

I am a software developer and studied Software Engineering in a BS program.
It is now 5 months that I have taken the final/8<sup>th</sup> semester exams but results have only been announced for 7 semesters yet.

Now, how should I mention following in my CV

- I am waiting for final semester result & result is expected in one and a half month.
- I have completed my BS program & I am available for full time.
- My CGPA for 7 semesters.

And, as I have been employed for about an year now, what should appear first in my CV my work experience or my educational qualifications.

Comment: @Lilienthal I think it some what different from mentioned question, I have completed classes and waiting for result while mentioned question is about mentioning a planned progr.am

Comment: The key point is that for both scenarios the standard way of listing an education like this is with an "expected" graduation date. It would be different if that date was a full semester away and you're available now, but that's not the case for you. As for your second question (work or education first), I suggest you ask that in a separate question. It doesn't seem to have been asked here before and while it's a trivial question, it's come up before as part of other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects. One is how to format your resume and the other is to how to let employers know you are looking for full-time positions.

With regards to formatting your resume or CV, you have not yet completed the program. Until the final grades are in and credit has been granted for all courses, you are still expecting to complete the program. This is usually indicated by simply putting the word "expected" before the month and year you graduate. For example:

```
BS Software Engineering
University Name
2012 - Present (Expected June 2016)
Description of Program. Current cumulative GPA, minors, concentrations, achievements.
```

After you receive your final grades, change "Present (Expected June 2016)" to read "2016". If you are still looking for full-time work, update the cumulative GPA. I dropped the GPA from my resume after a few years of work experience, but if you graduated with honors, you may want to continue to note that.

As far as looking for full-time jobs, you can indicate this by simply applying to entry level or recent graduate positions on company websites. If companies ask for transcripts, you can let them know when you will be receiving your final grades and ask them if they would like you to wait or send the most recent transcripts and then send an updated set of transcripts after the latest grades are available.

Comment: thanks @thomas, your response is highly appreciated.
I was looking to mention 2015 as my graduation year, as I appeared in last exams in Nov-Dec '15. But it seems i must mention 2016.

Comment: @MHS I'm not sure where you are, but in the United States, you haven't graduated until your last grades are in and the school has certified that you've met all of the requirements for graduation.

Comment: I'm from Pakistan and it is same here, that you are not considered a graduate until you have earned certificate.